# Add search bar to a d3 HEB (Hierarchical Edge Bundling) chart

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I'm trying to add a search bar on this HEB where we can search the elements of HEB and by clicking the search icon we can activate the element

I was trying to add search bar and when we click on search icon it will directed to the mouseovered function. I was also trying to add search bar such that it will give the suggestions of elements what we are typing.

[here is my code](https://jsfiddle.net/harshitdy009/vsgxkboq/#&togetherjs=zGu1PDat3s)

**Can any one please help me**

this image

[image]

belongs to another code I have just added the search bar but it was't worked properly. This is just an example to show you what I want to do.

```js
var data = [{
  "name": "flare.util.heap.FibonacciHeap",
  "size": 9354,
  "imports": ["flare.util.heap.HeapNode"]
}, {
  "name": "flare.util.heap.HeapNode",
  "size": 1233,
  "imports": ["flare.util.heap.FibonacciHeap"]
}, {
  "name": "flare.util.IEvaluable",
  "size": 335,
  "imports": []
}, {
  "name": "flare.util.IPredicate",
  "size": 383,
  "imports": []
}, {
  "name": "flare.util.IValueProxy",
  "size": 874,
  "imports": []
}, {
  "name": "flare.util.math.DenseMatrix",
  "size": 3165,
  "imports": ["flare.util.math.IMatrix"]
}, {
  "name": "flare.util.math.IMatrix",
  "size": 2815,
  "imports": []
}, {
  "name": "flare.util.math.SparseMatrix",
  "size": 3366,
  "imports": ["flare.util.math.IMatrix"]
}, {
  "name": "flare.util.Maths",
  "size": 17705,
  "imports": ["flare.util.Arrays"]
}, {
  "name": "flare.util.Orientation",
  "size": 1486,
  "imports": []
}, {
  "name": "flare.util.palette.ColorPalette",
  "size": 6367,
  "imports": ["flare.util.palette.Palette", "flare.util.Colors"]
}, {
  "name": "flare.util.palette.Palette",
  "size": 1229,
  "imports": []
}, {
  "name": "flare.util.palette.ShapePalette",
  "size": 2059,
  "imports": ["flare.util.palette.Palette", "flare.util.Shapes"]
}, {
  "name": "flare.util.palette.SizePalette",
  "size": 2291,
  "imports": ["flare.util.palette.Palette"]
}, {
  "name": "flare.util.Property",
  "size": 5559,
  "imports": ["flare.util.IPredicate", "flare.util.IValueProxy", "flare.util.IEvaluable"]
}, {
  "name": "flare.util.Shapes",
  "size": 19118,
  "imports": ["flare.util.Arrays"]
}, {
  "name": "flare.util.Sort",
  "size": 6887,
  "imports": ["flare.util.Arrays", "flare.util.Property"]
}, {
  "name": "flare.util.Stats",
  "size": 6557,
  "imports": ["flare.util.Arrays", "flare.util.Property"]
}, {
  "name": "flare.util.Strings",
  "size": 22026,
  "imports": ["flare.util.Dates", "flare.util.Property"]
}, {
  "name": "flare.vis.axis.Axes",
  "size": 1302,
  "imports": ["flare.animate.Transitioner", "flare.vis.Visualization"]
}, {
  "name": "flare.vis.axis.Axis",
  "size": 24593,
  "imports": ["flare.animate.Transitioner", "flare.scale.LinearScale", "flare.util.Arrays", "flare.scale.ScaleType", "flare.util.Strings", "flare.display.TextSprite", "flare.scale.Scale", "flare.util.Stats", "flare.scale.IScaleMap", "flare.vis.axis.AxisLabel", "flare.vis.axis.AxisGridLine"]
}, {
  "name": "flare.vis.axis.AxisGridLine",
  "size": 652,
  "imports": ["flare.vis.axis.Axis", "flare.display.LineSprite"]
}, {
  "name": "flare.vis.axis.AxisLabel",
  "size": 636,
  "imports": ["flare.vis.axis.Axis", "flare.display.TextSprite"]
}, {
  "name": "flare.vis.axis.CartesianAxes",
  "size": 6703,
  "imports": ["flare.animate.Transitioner", "flare.display.RectSprite", "flare.vis.axis.Axis", "flare.display.TextSprite", "flare.vis.axis.Axes", "flare.vis.Visualization", "flare.vis.axis.AxisGridLine"]
}, {
  "name": "flare.vis.controls.AnchorControl",
  "size": 2138,
  "imports": ["flare.vis.controls.Control", "flare.vis.Visualization", "flare.vis.operator.layout.Layout"]
}, {
  "name": "flare.vis.controls.ClickControl",
  "size": 3824,
  "imports": ["flare.vis.events.SelectionEvent", "flare.vis.controls.Control"]
}, {
  "name": "flare.vis.controls.Control",
  "size": 1353,
  "imports": ["flare.vis.controls.IControl", "flare.util.Filter"]
}, {
  "name": "flare.vis.controls.ControlList",
  "size": 4665,
  "imports": ["flare.vis.controls.IControl", "flare.util.Arrays", "flare.vis.Visualization", "flare.vis.controls.Control"]
}, {
  "name": "flare.vis.controls.DragControl",
  "size": 2649,
  "imports": ["flare.vis.controls.Control", "flare.vis.data.DataSprite"]
}, {
  "name": "flare.vis.controls.ExpandControl",
  "size": 2832,
  "imports": ["flare.animate.Transitioner", "flare.vis.data.NodeSprite", "flare.vis.controls.Control", "flare.vis.Visualization"]
}, {
  "name": "flare.vis.controls.HoverControl",
  "size": 4896,
  "imports": ["flare.vis.events.SelectionEvent", "flare.vis.controls.Control"]
}, {
  "name": "flare.vis.controls.IControl",
  "size": 763,
  "imports": ["flare.vis.controls.Control"]
}, {
  "name": "flare.vis.controls.PanZoomControl",
  "size": 5222,
  "imports": ["flare.util.Displays", "flare.vis.controls.Control"]
}, {
  "name": "flare.vis.controls.SelectionControl",
  "size": 7862,
  "imports": ["flare.vis.events.SelectionEvent", "flare.vis.controls.Control"]
}, {
  "name": "flare.vis.controls.TooltipControl",
  "size": 8435,
  "imports": ["flare.animate.Tween", "flare.display.TextSprite", "flare.vis.controls.Control", "flare.vis.events.TooltipEvent"]
}, {
  "name": "flare.vis.data.Data",
  "size": 20544,
  "imports": ["flare.vis.data.EdgeSprite", "flare.vis.data.NodeSprite", "flare.util.Arrays", "flare.vis.data.DataSprite", "flare.vis.data.Tree", "flare.vis.events.DataEvent", "flare.data.DataSet", "flare.vis.data.TreeBuilder", "flare.vis.data.DataList", "flare.data.DataSchema", "flare.util.Sort", "flare.data.DataField", "flare.util.Property"]
}, {
  "name": "flare.vis.data.DataList",
  "size": 19788,
  "imports": ["flare.animate.Transitioner", "flare.vis.data.NodeSprite", "flare.util.Arrays", "flare.util.math.DenseMatrix", "flare.vis.data.DataSprite", "flare.vis.data.EdgeSprite", "flare.vis.events.DataEvent", "flare.util.Stats", "flare.util.math.IMatrix", "flare.util.Sort", "flare.util.Filter", "flare.util.Property", "flare.util.IEvaluable", "flare.vis.data.Data"]
}, {
  "name": "flare.vis.data.DataSprite",
  "size": 10349,
  "imports": ["flare.util.Colors", "flare.vis.data.Data", "flare.display.DirtySprite", "flare.vis.data.render.IRenderer", "flare.vis.data.render.ShapeRenderer"]
}, {
  "name": "flare.vis.data.EdgeSprite",
  "size": 3301,
  "imports": ["flare.vis.data.render.EdgeRenderer", "flare.vis.data.DataSprite", "flare.vis.data.NodeSprite", "flare.vis.data.render.ArrowType", "flare.vis.data.Data"]
}, {
  "name": "flare.vis.data.NodeSprite",
  "size": 19382,
  "imports": ["flare.animate.Transitioner", "flare.util.Arrays", "flare.vis.data.DataSprite", "flare.vis.data.EdgeSprite", "flare.vis.data.Tree", "flare.util.Sort", "flare.util.Filter", "flare.util.IEvaluable", "flare.vis.data.Data"]
}, {
  "name": "flare.vis.data.render.ArrowType",
  "size": 698,
  "imports": []
}, {
  "name": "flare.vis.data.render.EdgeRenderer",
  "size": 5569,
  "imports": ["flare.vis.data.EdgeSprite", "flare.vis.data.NodeSprite", "flare.vis.data.DataSprite", "flare.vis.data.render.IRenderer", "flare.util.Shapes", "flare.util.Geometry", "flare.vis.data.render.ArrowType"]
}, {
  "name": "flare.vis.data.render.IRenderer",
  "size": 353,
  "imports": ["flare.vis.data.DataSprite"]
}, {
  "name": "flare.vis.data.render.ShapeRenderer",
  "size": 2247,
  "imports": ["flare.util.Shapes", "flare.vis.data.render.IRenderer", "flare.vis.data.DataSprite"]
}, {
  "name": "flare.vis.data.ScaleBinding",
  "size": 11275,
  "imports": ["flare.scale.TimeScale", "flare.scale.ScaleType", "flare.scale.LinearScale", "flare.scale.LogScale", "flare.scale.OrdinalScale", "flare.scale.RootScale", "flare.scale.Scale", "flare.scale.QuantileScale", "flare.util.Stats", "flare.scale.QuantitativeScale", "flare.vis.events.DataEvent", "flare.vis.data.Data"]
}, {
  "name": "flare.vis.data.Tree",
  "size": 7147,
  "imports": ["flare.vis.data.EdgeSprite", "flare.vis.events.DataEvent", "flare.vis.data.NodeSprite", "flare.vis.data.Data"]
}, {
  "name": "flare.vis.data.TreeBuilder",
  "size": 9930,
  "imports": ["flare.vis.data.EdgeSprite", "flare.vis.data.NodeSprite", "flare.vis.data.Tree", "flare.util.heap.HeapNode", "flare.util.heap.FibonacciHeap", "flare.util.Property", "flare.util.IEvaluable", "flare.vis.data.Data"]
}, {
  "name": "flare.vis.events.DataEvent",
  "size": 2313,
  "imports": ["flare.vis.data.EdgeSprite", "flare.vis.data.NodeSprite", "flare.vis.data.DataList", "flare.vis.data.DataSprite"]
}, {
  "name": "flare.vis.events.SelectionEvent",
  "size": 1880,
  "imports": ["flare.vis.events.DataEvent"]
}, {
  "name": "flare.vis.events.TooltipEvent",
  "size": 1701,
  "imports": ["flare.vis.data.EdgeSprite", "flare.vis.data.NodeSprite"]
}, {
  "name": "flare.vis.events.VisualizationEvent",
  "size": 1117,
  "imports": ["flare.animate.Transitioner"]
}, {
  "name": "flare.vis.legend.Legend",
  "size": 20859,
  "imports": ["flare.animate.Transitioner", "flare.vis.data.ScaleBinding", "flare.util.palette.SizePalette", "flare.scale.ScaleType", "flare.vis.legend.LegendItem", "flare.display.RectSprite", "flare.display.TextSprite", "flare.scale.Scale", "flare.vis.legend.LegendRange", "flare.util.Displays", "flare.util.Orientation", "flare.util.palette.ShapePalette", "flare.util.palette.Palette", "flare.util.palette.ColorPalette"]
}, {
  "name": "flare.vis.legend.LegendItem",
  "size": 4614,
  "imports": ["flare.util.Shapes", "flare.display.TextSprite", "flare.vis.legend.Legend", "flare.display.RectSprite"]
}, {
  "name": "flare.vis.legend.LegendRange",
  "size": 10530,
  "imports": ["flare.util.Colors", "flare.vis.legend.Legend", "flare.display.RectSprite", "flare.display.TextSprite", "flare.scale.Scale", "flare.util.Stats", "flare.scale.IScaleMap", "flare.util.Orientation", "flare.util.palette.ColorPalette"]
}, {
  "name": "flare.vis.operator.distortion.BifocalDistortion",
  "size": 4461,
  "imports": ["flare.vis.operator.distortion.Distortion"]
}, {
  "name": "flare.vis.operator.distortion.Distortion",
  "size": 6314,
  "imports": ["flare.animate.Transitioner", "flare.vis.data.DataSprite", "flare.vis.events.VisualizationEvent", "flare.vis.axis.Axis", "flare.vis.axis.CartesianAxes", "flare.vis.operator.layout.Layout", "flare.vis.data.Data"]
}, {
  "name": "flare.vis.operator.distortion.FisheyeDistortion",
  "size": 3444,
  "imports": ["flare.vis.operator.distortion.Distortion"]
}, {
  "name": "flare.vis.operator.encoder.ColorEncoder",
  "size": 3179,
  "imports": ["flare.animate.Transitioner", "flare.scale.ScaleType", "flare.vis.operator.encoder.Encoder", "flare.util.palette.Palette", "flare.util.palette.ColorPalette", "flare.vis.data.Data"]
}, {
  "name": "flare.vis.operator.encoder.Encoder",
  "size": 4060,
  "imports": ["flare.animate.Transitioner", "flare.vis.data.DataSprite", "flare.vis.operator.Operator", "flare.vis.data.ScaleBinding", "flare.util.palette.Palette", "flare.util.Filter", "flare.util.Property", "flare.vis.data.Data"]
}, {
  "name": "flare.vis.operator.encoder.PropertyEncoder",
  "size": 4138,
  "imports": ["flare.animate.Transitioner", "flare.vis.data.DataList", "flare.vis.data.Data", "flare.vis.operator.encoder.Encoder", "flare.util.Filter", "flare.vis.operator.Operator"]
}, {
  "name": "flare.vis.operator.encoder.ShapeEncoder",
  "size": 1690,
  "imports": ["flare.util.palette.Palette", "flare.scale.ScaleType", "flare.util.palette.ShapePalette", "flare.vis.operator.encoder.Encoder", "flare.vis.data.Data"]
}, {
  "name": "flare.vis.operator.encoder.SizeEncoder",
  "size": 1830,
  "imports": ["flare.util.palette.Palette", "flare.scale.ScaleType", "flare.vis.operator.encoder.Encoder", "flare.util.palette.SizePalette", "flare.vis.data.Data"]
}, {
  "name": "flare.vis.operator.filter.FisheyeTreeFilter",
  "size": 5219,
  "imports": ["flare.animate.Transitioner", "flare.vis.data.NodeSprite", "flare.vis.data.DataSprite", "flare.vis.data.EdgeSprite", "flare.vis.data.Tree", "flare.vis.operator.Operator", "flare.vis.data.Data"]
}, {
  "name": "flare.vis.operator.filter.GraphDistanceFilter",
  "size": 3165,
  "imports": ["flare.animate.Transitioner", "flare.vis.data.NodeSprite", "flare.vis.operator.Operator", "flare.vis.data.DataSprite", "flare.vis.data.EdgeSprite"]
}, {
  "name": "flare.vis.operator.filter.VisibilityFilter",
  "size": 3509,
  "imports": ["flare.vis.operator.Operator", "flare.animate.Transitioner", "flare.util.Filter", "flare.vis.data.DataSprite", "flare.vis.data.Data"]
}, {
  "name": "flare.vis.operator.IOperator",
  "size": 1286,
  "imports": ["flare.animate.Transitioner", "flare.vis.Visualization", "flare.vis.operator.Operator"]
}, {
  "name": "flare.vis.operator.label.Labeler",
  "size": 9956,
  "imports": ["flare.animate.Transitioner", "flare.vis.data.DataSprite", "flare.display.TextSprite", "flare.vis.operator.Operator", "flare.util.Shapes", "flare.util.Filter", "flare.util.Property", "flare.util.IEvaluable", "flare.vis.data.Data"]
}, {
  "name": "flare.vis.operator.label.RadialLabeler",
  "size": 3899,
  "imports": ["flare.vis.operator.label.Labeler", "flare.util.Shapes", "flare.display.TextSprite", "flare.vis.data.DataSprite", "flare.vis.data.Data"]
}, {
  "name": "flare.vis.operator.label.StackedAreaLabeler",
  "size": 3202,
  "imports": ["flare.vis.operator.label.Labeler", "flare.display.TextSprite", "flare.vis.data.DataSprite", "flare.vis.data.Data"]
}, {
  "name": "flare.vis.operator.layout.AxisLayout",
  "size": 6725,
  "imports": ["flare.scale.ScaleType", "flare.vis.data.DataSprite", "flare.vis.axis.CartesianAxes", "flare.vis.data.ScaleBinding", "flare.util.Property", "flare.vis.operator.layout.Layout", "flare.vis.data.Data"]
}, {
  "name": "flare.vis.operator.layout.BundledEdgeRouter",
  "size": 3727,
  "imports": ["flare.animate.Transitioner", "flare.vis.data.NodeSprite", "flare.util.Arrays", "flare.vis.data.DataSprite", "flare.vis.data.EdgeSprite", "flare.util.Shapes", "flare.vis.operator.layout.Layout", "flare.vis.operator.Operator"]
}, {
  "name": "flare.vis.operator.layout.CircleLayout",
  "size": 9317,
  "imports": ["flare.vis.data.NodeSprite", "flare.vis.data.DataList", "flare.vis.data.ScaleBinding", "flare.util.Property", "flare.vis.operator.layout.Layout", "flare.vis.data.Data"]
}, {
  "name": "flare.vis.operator.layout.CirclePackingLayout",
  "size": 12003,
  "imports": ["flare.vis.data.NodeSprite", "flare.vis.data.render.ShapeRenderer", "flare.util.Shapes", "flare.util.Sort", "flare.vis.operator.layout.Layout", "flare.vis.data.Data"]
}, {
  "name": "flare.vis.operator.layout.DendrogramLayout",
  "size": 4853,
  "imports": ["flare.util.Property", "flare.vis.data.NodeSprite", "flare.util.Orientation", "flare.vis.operator.layout.Layout", "flare.vis.data.EdgeSprite"]
}, {
  "name": "flare.vis.operator.layout.ForceDirectedLayout",
  "size": 8411,
  "imports": ["flare.physics.Simulation", "flare.animate.Transitioner", "flare.vis.data.NodeSprite", "flare.vis.data.DataSprite", "flare.physics.Particle", "flare.physics.Spring", "flare.vis.operator.layout.Layout", "flare.vis.data.EdgeSprite", "flare.vis.data.Data"]
}, {
  "name": "flare.vis.operator.layout.IcicleTreeLayout",
  "size": 4864,
  "imports": ["flare.vis.data.NodeSprite", "flare.util.Orientation", "flare.vis.operator.layout.Layout"]
}, {
  "name": "flare.vis.operator.layout.IndentedTreeLayout",
  "size": 3174,
  "imports": ["flare.animate.Transitioner", "flare.vis.data.NodeSprite", "flare.util.Arrays", "flare.vis.operator.layout.Layout", "flare.vis.data.EdgeSprite"]
}, {
  "name": "flare.vis.operator.layout.Layout",
  "size": 7881,
  "imports": ["flare.animate.Transitioner", "flare.vis.data.NodeSprite", "flare.vis.data.DataList", "flare.vis.data.DataSprite", "flare.vis.data.EdgeSprite", "flare.vis.Visualization", "flare.vis.axis.CartesianAxes", "flare.vis.axis.Axes", "flare.animate.TransitionEvent", "flare.vis.operator.Operator"]
}, {
  "name": "flare.vis.operator.layout.NodeLinkTreeLayout",
  "size": 12870,
  "imports": ["flare.vis.data.NodeSprite", "flare.util.Arrays", "flare.util.Orientation", "flare.vis.operator.layout.Layout"]
}, {
  "name": "flare.vis.operator.layout.PieLayout",
  "size": 2728,
  "imports": ["flare.vis.data.DataList", "flare.vis.data.DataSprite", "flare.util.Shapes", "flare.util.Property", "flare.vis.operator.layout.Layout", "flare.vis.data.Data"]
}, {
  "name": "flare.vis.operator.layout.RadialTreeLayout",
  "size": 12348,
  "imports": ["flare.vis.data.NodeSprite", "flare.util.Arrays", "flare.vis.operator.layout.Layout"]
}, {
  "name": "flare.vis.operator.layout.RandomLayout",
  "size": 870,
  "imports": ["flare.vis.operator.layout.Layout", "flare.vis.data.DataSprite", "flare.vis.data.Data"]
}, {
  "name": "flare.vis.operator.layout.StackedAreaLayout",
  "size": 9121,
  "imports": ["flare.scale.TimeScale", "flare.scale.LinearScale", "flare.util.Arrays", "flare.scale.OrdinalScale", "flare.vis.data.NodeSprite", "flare.scale.Scale", "flare.vis.axis.CartesianAxes", "flare.util.Stats", "flare.util.Orientation", "flare.scale.QuantitativeScale", "flare.util.Maths", "flare.vis.operator.layout.Layout"]
}, {
  "name": "flare.vis.operator.layout.TreeMapLayout",
  "size": 9191,
  "imports": ["flare.animate.Transitioner", "flare.vis.data.NodeSprite", "flare.util.Property", "flare.vis.operator.layout.Layout"]
}, {
  "name": "flare.vis.operator.Operator",
  "size": 2490,
  "imports": ["flare.animate.Transitioner", "flare.vis.operator.IOperator", "flare.util.Property", "flare.util.IEvaluable", "flare.vis.Visualization"]
}, {
  "name": "flare.vis.operator.OperatorList",
  "size": 5248,
  "imports": ["flare.animate.Transitioner", "flare.util.Arrays", "flare.vis.operator.IOperator", "flare.vis.Visualization", "flare.vis.operator.Operator"]
}, {
  "name": "flare.vis.operator.OperatorSequence",
  "size": 4190,
  "imports": ["flare.animate.Transitioner", "flare.util.Arrays", "flare.vis.operator.IOperator", "flare.vis.operator.OperatorList", "flare.animate.FunctionSequence", "flare.vis.operator.Operator"]
}, {
  "name": "flare.vis.operator.OperatorSwitch",
  "size": 2581,
  "imports": ["flare.animate.Transitioner", "flare.vis.operator.OperatorList", "flare.vis.operator.IOperator", "flare.vis.operator.Operator"]
}, {
  "name": "flare.vis.operator.SortOperator",
  "size": 2023,
  "imports": ["flare.vis.operator.Operator", "flare.animate.Transitioner", "flare.util.Arrays", "flare.vis.data.Data"]
}, {
  "name": "flare.vis.Visualization",
  "size": 16540,
  "imports": ["flare.animate.Transitioner", "flare.vis.operator.IOperator", "flare.animate.Scheduler", "flare.vis.events.VisualizationEvent", "flare.vis.data.Tree", "flare.vis.events.DataEvent", "flare.vis.axis.Axes", "flare.vis.axis.CartesianAxes", "flare.util.Displays", "flare.vis.operator.OperatorList", "flare.vis.controls.ControlList", "flare.animate.ISchedulable", "flare.vis.data.Data"]
}];


var diameter = 960,
  radius = diameter / 2,
  innerRadius = radius - 120;
var cluster = d3.layout.cluster()
  .size([360, innerRadius])
  .sort(null)
  .value(function(d) {
    return d.size;
  });
var bundle = d3.layout.bundle();
var line = d3.svg.line.radial()
  .interpolate("bundle")
  .tension(.85)
  .radius(function(d) {
    return d.y;
  })
  .angle(function(d) {
    return d.x / 180 * Math.PI;
  });

var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
  .scaleExtent([0, 8])
  .on("zoom", zoomhandler);

var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
  .origin(function(d) {
    return d;
  })
  .on("dragstart", dragstarted)
  .on("drag", dragged)
  .on("dragend", dragended);

var svg = d3.select(".container").append("svg")
  .attr("width", diameter)
  .attr("height", diameter)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + radius + "," + radius + ")")
  .call(zoom)
  .call(drag);

function zoomhandler() {
  svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
}

function dragstarted(d) {
  d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
  d3.select(this).classed("dragging", true);
}

function dragged(d) {
  d3.select(this).attr("cx", d.x = d3.event.x).attr("cy", d.y = d3.event.y);
}

function dragended(d) {
  d3.select(this).classed("dragging", false);
}

var link = svg.append("g").selectAll(".link"),
  node = svg.append("g").selectAll(".node");


var nodes = cluster.nodes(packageHierarchy(data)),
  links = packageImports(nodes);
link = link
  .data(bundle(links))
  .enter().append("path")
  .each(function(d) {
    d.source = d[0], d.target = d[d.length - 1];
  })
  .attr("class", "link")
  .attr("d", line)
  .on('click', function(d) {
    alert('mouseover');
  });
node = node
  .data(nodes.filter(function(n) {
    return !n.children;
  }))
  .enter().append("text")
  .attr("class", "node")
  .attr("dy", ".31em")
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "rotate(" + (d.x - 90) + ")translate(" + (d.y + 8) + ",0)" + (d.x < 180 ? "" : "rotate(180)");
  })
  .style("text-anchor", function(d) {
    return d.x < 180 ? "start" : "end";
  })
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.key;
  })
  .on("mouseover", mouseovered)
  .on("mouseout", mouseouted);

d3.select(".container").on("mousemove", function() {
  fisheye.focus(d3.mouse(this));

  node.each(function(d) {
      d.fisheye = fisheye(d);
    })
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return d.fisheye.x;
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) {
      return d.fisheye.y;
    });
  //.attr("r", function(d) { return d.fisheye.z * 4.5; });

  link.attr("x1", function(d) {
      return d.source.fisheye.x;
    })
    .attr("y1", function(d) {
      return d.source.fisheye.y;
    })
    .attr("x2", function(d) {
      return d.target.fisheye.x;
    })
    .attr("y2", function(d) {
      return d.target.fisheye.y;
    });
});

function mouseovered(d) {
  node
    .each(function(n) {
      n.target = n.source = false;
    });
  link
    .classed("link--target", function(l) {
      if (l.target === d) return l.source.source = true;
    })
    .classed("link--source", function(l) {
      if (l.source === d) return l.target.target = true;
    })
    .filter(function(l) {
      return l.target === d || l.source === d;
    })
    .each(function() {
      this.parentNode.appendChild(this);
    });
  node
    .classed("node--target", function(n) {
      return n.target;
    })
    .classed("node--source", function(n) {
      return n.source;
    });
}

function mouseouted(d) {
  link
    .classed("link--target", false)
    .classed("link--source", false);
  node
    .classed("node--target", false)
    .classed("node--source", false);
}

d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", diameter + "px");
// Lazily construct the package hierarchy from class names.
function packageHierarchy(classes) {
  var map = {};

  function find(name, data) {
    var node = map[name],
      i;
    if (!node) {
      node = map[name] = data || {
        name: name,
        children: []
      };
      if (name.length) {
        node.parent = find(name.substring(0, i = name.lastIndexOf(".")));
        node.parent.children.push(node);
        node.key = name.substring(i + 1);
      }
    }
    return node;
  }
  classes.forEach(function(d) {
    find(d.name, d);
  });
  return map[""];
}
// Return a list of imports for the given array of nodes.
function packageImports(nodes) {
  var map = {},
    imports = [];
  // Compute a map from name to node.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    map[d.name] = d;
  });
  // For each import, construct a link from the source to target node.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    if (d.imports) d.imports.forEach(function(i) {
      imports.push({
        source: map[d.name],
        target: map[i]
      });
    });
  });
  return imports;
}
```

```css
.node {
  font: 300 11px "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  fill: #bbb;
}

.node:hover {
  fill: #000;
}

.link {
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-opacity: .4;
  fill: none;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.node:hover,
.node--source,
.node--target {
  font-weight: 700;
}

.node--source {
  fill: #2ca02c;
}

.node--target {
  fill: #d62728;
}

.link--source,
.link--target {
  stroke-opacity: 1;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}

.link--source {
  stroke: #d62728;
}

.link--target {
  stroke: #2ca02c;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

<body>
  <div class="container"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Your snippet gives error

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).